# Issue with data from the database resetting and disappearing Livewire Laravel

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I have a mount function that calls 2 tables and joins together but which works on first render. The issue I have is every time the component renders after that, the table joining the main one disappears leaving only the main table. So I have 2 tables joining (domestic+international). After it renders after mount it only leaves me with the domestic table with international gone.[image: On first render]
[image: After render]

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\ShippingDomestic;
use App\Models\ShippingInternational;

class ShippingList extends Component
{

    protected $listeners = ['refreshComponent' => '$refresh'];

    public $checkbox;
    public $class;
    public $shipping;

    public function mount(){

        $store = get_store()->first();

        $domestics = get_domestic_shipping();

        foreach ($domestics as $key => $domestic) {
            $domestic->international = ShippingInternational::where('shipping_id',$domestic->id)->get();
        }

        $this->shipping = $domestics; 
    }

    public function delete_shipping($id){

        $store = get_store()->first();

        $product = Product::where('shippingMethod',$id)->where('store_id',$store->id)->get();

        if (count($product) > 0) {
            return $this->addError('error', 'Method is attached to one of your listings');
        }else{
            ShippingDomestic::where('id',$id)->where('store_id',$store->id)->delete();
            ShippingInternational::where('shipping_id',$id)->delete();
        }

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.shipping-list');
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Livewire rehydrate the models between the call. What if you use `$domestic->setRelation('international', $international)`? Assuming the relation `international` exists on the model `Domestic`

Comment: Also, as alternative, instead of using `public $shipping;` you can use [computed property](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#computed-properties) `public function getShippingProperty()`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
->toArray()
```

if you wish to join multiple tables on mount, though it's not recomended. relationships can do that and read this: https://calebporzio.com/how-livewire-works-a-deep-dive

Collections and models are rehydrated on each request.